# Internalize creation of MPI processes

Tags: mpi

Is there a way to internalize the creation of MPI processes? Instead of specifying the number of processes in the commandline "mpiexec -np 2 ./[PROG]"; I would like the number of processes be specified internally.
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Yes.   You're looking for [MPI_Spawn()](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-20-html/node98.htm) from MPI-2, which launches a (possibly different) program with a number of processes that can be specified at runtime, and creates a new communicatator which you can use in place of MPI_COMM_WORLD to communicate amongst both the original and the new processes.